# File upload and file down controls are not working. I've attached the code below. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using file upload control to upload file to xpage and it is not saving file thru submit button. This submit button also does lot of other activities.

The following link says it is a issue in 8.5.3 client(i'm using 8.5.3FP6 client and server) and going to fix in next release. Any body has workaround for saving uploaded files.?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO72380

Here is button code which is doing full refresh:

```
<xp:button
                value="TSS Submit For approval"
                id="button3">
                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript://@If ((Proj_submitted_DT = "" ) & (@Name([Abbreviate] ; Champion_TX) = @Name([Abbreviate] ; @UserName )) & (Doc_Stage_TX = "Stage 1") ; @False ;@True)
document1.isEditable() & document1.isNewNote() &(@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",document1.getItemValueString("TSSTSMSalesMan")) == @Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName())); 
//& ((document1.getItemValueDate("Proj_submitted_DT")=="") & (@Name(["ABBREVIATE"],document1.getItemValueString("Champion_TX")) == @Name(["ABBREVIATE"],@UserName())) & (document1.getItemValueString("Doc_Stage_TX") == "Stage 1") )){
//return false;
//} else {
//return true;
//}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete"
                    immediate="false"
                    save="true">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript://var h=getComponent("docHistory1").getValue();
var inputTextarea2:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputTextarea = getComponent("inputTextarea2");
var h=inputTextarea2.getValue()
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
var dt1=@Left(dt.toJavaDate()," ");
var unm=@Name("[CN]", @UserName());
var myvar = @NewLine();
var lnm=getComponent("computedField1").getValue();
var pdoc:NotesDocument=database.getProfileDocument("LastNumber","")
var msg="Stage 1 - Lab Request Submitted to the Lab Manager by Project Champion : " + unm + " - " + dt1;
document1.setValue("Proj_submitted_DT",@Today());
document1.save();
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
var noteid=doc.getNoteID();
var ag=session.getCurrentDatabase().getAgent('St1MetalWorkEmailToTSMRSM');
ag.runOnServer(noteid);}]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                            <xp:openPage name="/XpOne.xsp"></xp:openPage>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

This is file upload which is bind to rich text field

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" value="#{document1.RawData}">
                                </xp:fileUpload>
```

Comment: The fileupload control and the submit button is working well. Your code is the problem.

Comment: Code! We need code! As Sven pointed out: works as designed. I also suggest to rephrase your titles to not contain assertions about product deficiencies, but state a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a document.save() in your code. That saves the document without the uploaded file. You need to make a set of changes:

- remove the code from the button so it only saves - this should make the upload work.
- split the code into two: part 1 is everything before the save statement. Part 2 everything after. Both times without the save statement
- move part 1 into the QuerySave event of your data source
- move part 2 into the post save event

That should do the trick. A common anti-pattern in Domino: getting into the way of the build in life cycle

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure file upload is working, I did not put the code in querysave and post save event and button made save only with full refresh and save button did not saved the attachment.

Comment: Ran compact, fixup on the file and it worked.  I'm working on workflow application and the button is in last stage of workflow. If I add the button code to querysave and possave events, that code will run for every stage. STill I've to work on this button. Thanks again.

Comment: I still would put that code into the querySave / postSave events. Use a state variable to conditionally execute it. And when I say "into" that would be one call to a script library, not the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Check so the document is saved without adding a file, also check in different webbrowsers. Also if you run pre v9.0.1 make sure you are using full refresh in the button

Comment: Thanks. I'm using full refresh and document is saved properly except attachment. I attached the file in notes client and tried to download it in web xpage using file download control and it is also not working.

Comment: is the file download and file upload control bound to a document data source? 

I think you need to update your post with more information and some xml/xsp editor code so we better understand what is going on.

Comment: I suggest you create a new button with a click action to do only document1.save() and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on workflow application and the button in question is for last stage of the workflow. Checked the team room xpage code for attachment and I solved the problem as follows:

1. Changed the button type to 'Button' from 'Sumbit'
2. Created 1s action execute script and added code to change field values. This script does not have document1.save() code
3. Created a second action to save document.
4. The file upload control was bound to rich text field and uploaded file and click the button to run script and save document.

The attachment was saved.

Mohan Gangan.